# Converting Strings with delimiter into table using trigger

Tags: database, database-trigger

Good day,

I have this string "Column1=value1|Column2=value2|Column3=value3|"....and so on.
I want to create a table using the given string.I'll be using a database trigger.Is it Possible to create the header based on the string? or do i need to create a table that already has the column name for "Column1" "Column2" and "Column3"?
**OUTPUT:**
Column1 Column2 Column3
value1.....value2.....value3

I also tried this as function

`IF @index = 0
RETURN( LEFT(@array, CHARINDEX('|', @array) - 1) )
DECLARE @counter INT
SELECT @counter = 0
WHILE @counter < @index
BEGIN
IF (CHARINDEX('|', @array) <> 0)
SELECT @array = SUBSTRING(@array, CHARINDEX('|', @array) + 1, LEN(@array))
ELSE
SELECT @array = ''
SELECT @counter = @counter + 1
END
IF CHARINDEX('|', @array) != 0
SELECT @array = LEFT(@array, CHARINDEX('|', @array) - 1)
RETURN( @array )`
So i ran it as a function and the output is
**"Column1=Value1"**
So i think i need to create another function where the header and its value can be separated, but as i said, i don't know if it's possible to not create the header ahead and based the header on the string.
**NOTE:** The header is fixed so if it's not possible to based the header on the string, that would be ok BUT if it's possible then that would be great.
Any help is appreciated, Thanks